# Subtypes of Acute myeloid leukemia

Tags: immunology, pathology, cancer

I am a computer scientist with no biological background and working on analyzing lab  results of patients with Acute myeloid leukemia. They have been tagged with following subtypes of AML:

- AML with No maturation
- AML with granulocytic differentiation
- AML with monocytic  differentitaion.

I know there are two classifications for AML subtypes: FAB(M0-M7) and WHO. I think these patients have been classified using FAB, but their corresponding subtypes' names do not match in any of the names associated with M0-M7:  http://www.cancer.org/cancer/leukemia-acutemyeloidaml/detailedguide/leukemia-acute-myeloid-myelogenous-classified.

I checked a lot of literature but still not sure about the class of the last two tags in FAB classification. Could someone please help me with that?

- "AML with No maturation"  is M1?
- "AML with granulocytic differentiation" is M2 (or M4, M5) ?
- "AML with monocytic  differentiation" is M4 or M5 or both ?